# spacemonger option to skip symbolic links to other disks?

Tags: symlink

Is there an option in spacemonger (version 1.4) to skip folders that are symbolic links to other disks?

I'm using spacemonger on a virtual server that has folders that are symbolic links to folders on completely different computers. One of these happens to be a folder containing thousands of video files, which not only slows down spacemonger, but inflates the size of the drive it's analyzing so that it shows it's 171% used.

I've checked the visible options, and I've looked for online documentation, but haven't found any.